# How to send email after Sonar Scan/ Quality Gate in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

What I want to do is send email to users after each build with a link to Sonarqube server for that project/branch scan.

```
def sendEmailAfterSonarScan() {
soanrUrl = "http://lcoalhost:8080"
    { steps, domain, config ->

        steps.emailext(to: "email@mydomain.com", body: '$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS - $BUILD_URL ' + 'Please click the following link to view Sonar Report $sonarUrl', mimeType: 'text/html', subject: 'Sonar Report')
    }
}
```

but the method fails in the pipeline with error $sonarUrl not recognised. What am I doing wrong ?
I don't know groovy, but suspect is it something to do with double or triple quotes ?

Comment: Did you define sonarUrl variable or parameter in you pipeline?

Comment: No,I haven't and I can't. Pipeline is controlled by a central team and not customizable.

Comment: Isn't there a typo in `"http://lcoalhost:8080"` instead of `"http://localhost:8080"`?

Comment: yes,sorry there is a typo. But it's not the link that is incorrect, the link coming in the email just prints ${sonarUrl} as plain text.

Comment: It's not clear how sendEmailAfterSonarScan os used. Full piplene code is needed to understand reasons of malfunction.